# foreign key constraint violation when trying to clear a OneToOne relationship using a JoinTable

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following two entities:

```
@Entity
public class RoomEntity {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable(
        name = "room_camera_association",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "room_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "camera_id")}
    )
    private CameraEntity camera;
```

...and:

```
@Entity
public class CameraEntity {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "camera")
    private RoomEntity room;
```

... with the association table being defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE room_camera_association
(
    camera_id UUID NOT NULL,
    room_id UUID NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (camera_id, room_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_camera FOREIGN KEY (camera_id) REFERENCES camera(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_room FOREIGN KEY (room_id) REFERENCES room(id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_rca_camera_room UNIQUE (camera_id, room_id)
);
```

When I delete a room, I don't want to delete a camera. Likewise, if I delete a camera I don't want to delete a room.

When I execute the following code:

```
        for (RoomEntity room: getRooms()) {
            CameraEntity camera = room.getCamera();
            if (camera != null) {
                log.info("Removing camera {} association for room {}", camera.getName(), room.getName());
                room.setCamera(null);
                camera.setRoom(null);
                roomRepository.save(room);
                cameraRepository.save(camera);
            }
```

... and then subsequently do:

```
roomRepository.delete(room);
```

... I get the following exception:

```
2023-11-16 12:50:10.959 ERROR 1641464 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: update or delete on table "room" violates foreign key constraint "fk_room" on table "room_camera_association"
  Detail: Key (id)=(385a510c-bd26-4f89-8077-6e6b9aa78e31) is still referenced from table "room_camera_association".
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. We also have triggers setup to audit data that is being modified or deleted. The trigger function was setup like so:

```
INSERT INTO camera_association_log
    VALUES (NEW.*, 'DELETE'); RETURN NEW;
```

... and the trigger was `BEFORE DELETE ON`.

This was effectively preventing the deletes from happening, but this was happening silently. When I switched the function to `RETURN OLD` and the trigger to `AFTER DELETE ON`, this code started working:

```
  room.setCamera(null);
  camera.setRoom(null);
  roomRepository.save(room);
  cameraRepository.save(camera);
```

... automatically removing the record from the association table and allowing the subsequent room delete to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have specified (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}).

Try changing it to `(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})`

This is because you don't want CascadeType.REMOVE have effect.

Also try removing room_camera_association before removing room by -  `entityManager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM room_camera_association WHERE room_id = :roomId").setParameter("roomId", room.getId()).executeUpdate(); roomRepository.delete(room);`

Comment: Actually it was happening without the cascade. That was in my post unintentionally. I've removed it. But I have not tried with REFRESH and DETACH. Let me try that.

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: Okay this is happening because the room_camera_association still exists with the room_id and camera_id. So before deleting the room or camera, you will have to delete the room_camera_association by doing something like - entityManager.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM room_camera_association WHERE room_id = :roomId").setParameter("roomId", room.getId()).executeUpdate();
roomRepository.delete(room);

Comment: Shouldn't JPA handle removing the data from the @JoinTable?

Comment: JPA doesn't manage the associations on join tables by default. In this case the relationship is owned by both RoomEntity and CameraEntity. Also cascading will not delete manually managed join tables like in your case is for room_camera_association

Comment: I don't think that this is true. I did get my code to work without the manual delete of the association table record. It was a delete trigger that was preventing the JPA delete from working. I'll post most details in a follow up answer.